# For Humble Bundles, if I use a multiplayer key and then uninstall, is the key still valid for others?

Tags: drm, humble-bundle

I'm not trying to sell or make a profit or anything. It's just that one of the games I installed I ended up not liking very much. However my friend really wants to give it a try, but I don't know if it'll work since my multiplayer key is used. If I uninstall, will the game 'know' that my key isn't used and thus let my friend use it?

Comment: Which game is this?  I think it might vary per-game.  Also, the Humble Bundle guys generally want you to use the bundle for you only, and not divide it up.  From their FAQ: "Please consider your bundle a "unit", and not to share copies of the games or Steam keys from it."

Comment: Keys are only for yourself I believe. But this is a small problem I know.. but otherwise only one person would need to buy a copy and like a thousand people could play!

Comment: Is this a question of the game or possibly Steam or Desura?

Answer (score 3):

This depends mainly whether the keys used are associated with an account. It used to be that if you gave a friend a game that you no longer wanted and it's key there would not be an issue. Nowadays keys are mainly used in conjunction with some kind of online account making them a one time use deal. So if the game does use an account association for the keys, all you can do is ask to transfer it.